# Angular UI Router - breaks without href attribute

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get angular UI router to work. It was all fine in a standard web project, until I imported into a .net project and everything seemed to break. Namely:

```
<a ui-sref="someUrl">Click here</a>
```

does not work, when it did in the previous project.
The interesting catch is, if I add an href attribute with a value (can't be an empty string), the click works. This is annoying because my two environments with the same code are acting differently.

**Does anyone know why the ui-router would break without an explicit href attribute set on the tag?** The git docs state expressly *with a code example* that the anchor tag only needs the ui-sref attribute, because it will write the href tag on its own when applicable.

I'm using angular 1.3.2 and angular-ui-router.0.2.11.

Code:

```
<h2>Home Page</h2>

<a href="#" ui-sref="someState">Click for profile</a>
<div ui-view="someStateContainer"></div>
```

That is *literally* all of the base html inside the body.

main.js:

```
/**
 * Primary application definition
 */
var App = App || angular.module("App", [
    "ui.router"
]);


App.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("someState", {
                views: {
                    "someStateContainer": {
                        templateUrl: "states/testState"
                    }
                }
            })
}]);
```

Comment: when you say this link doesn't work, what is it going to when you click it?

Comment: Sorry - should have clarified. "Nothing" happens - e.g. you click, and there is no reaction whatsoever, as if this were a paragraph or a span. There's not even a request made in fiddler. I'll update OP with some code, since that's helpful....

Comment: is your code in a .html page or in a razor .cshtml? and what does the link actually look like in the view source rendered in the browser?

Comment: .cshtml. The link looks like so:  
<a href="#" ui-sref="someState">Click for profile</a>

Comment: it looks like that when you add the href or when you leave it out?

Comment: It looks like that when I add it. This is the only way to get the code to work. The ui-router is NOT modifying the href attribute (because there's no url on "someState").

Comment: so what does the `<a>` tag look like if you don't add the href attribute? I understand the link won't work, but that's the state you are trying to reach; I suspect that razor is doing something to the link tag because it is missing the href.

Comment: It outputs it verbatim, without the href. Thus all the head scratching... there's nothing markup-wise that is off here; methinks that .net is injecting something else into the page that is interfering, because this works in my project outside of visual studio...!!!

Comment: I don't know that there's much anyone can do. I'll troubleshoot on my end and update when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

An `<a>` tag MUST have an `href` attribute to be considered a link. UiRouter's `ui-sref` is just a way to instruct uiRouter on how to derive the proper `href`, which it will then set on the element.

I've noticed that under certain circumstances, uiRouter does *not* set an `href`. In my case, there was a state defined with `url: "/dashboard"`. However, `ui-sref="/dashboard"` would not generate an `href` attribute (not even an error). I had to set `ui-sref="dashboard"` so uiRouter would generate `href="#/dashboard"`. Maybe there are more situations in which uiRouter fails without error.

HTH

Comment: Its all good, we're on Ng2 now... for like 2 years. This is now irrelevant.